# JSF Displaying Text in modal if INSERT operation was successful

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, jsf, jsf-2

What is the correct way to return a value from a method in a managed bean indicating a successful `SQL` `DML` operation such as `INSERT` or `UPDATE`

Based on the tutorials and some blogs I read online, it says that a good practice in returning values from a method contained in a `ManagedBean` is a `String` value of a `facelet` or the `.xhtml` page 
(in other words, a **view**) to redirect to a webpage.

Like this.

**Original** version:

```
@ManagedBean(name="myBean")
public class MyBean{
    public String register(){
        String SQL = "INSERT INTO myTable(col1,col2) VALUES(?,?);  
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(SQL);
        ps.setString(1,someStringVariable1);
        ps.setString(2,someStringVariable2);
        ps.executeUpdate();

        return "index"; //pointing to index.xhtml
    }
}
```

How about if i want to know if the `executeUpdate()` method was successful?

I thought I'd just change it to something like

**Modified** version:

```
    public int register(){
        int isSuccessful = 0;
        try{
            String SQL = "INSERT INTO myTable(col1,col2) VALUES(?,?);  
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(SQL);
            ps.setString(1,someStringVariable1);
            ps.setString(2,someStringVariable2);

            isSuccessful = ps.executeUpdate();
        }
        return isSuccessful;
    }
```

However, on the modified version I returned an `int` which I don't see as correct as per how `JSF` should work with `ManagedBean` *(Please correct me if i'm wrong)*

I asked because say I have a **Twitter Bootstrap** `modal` which has the following.

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <h:form>
        //....some code here...

        <h:commandButton value="Submit" action=#{myBean.register()}
        <h:outputText value=" #{myBean.whatToPutHere_ToKnowIf_addData()wasSuccessful}" />
    </h:form>
</div>
```

I need to be able to show within the `modal` `div` that `register()` execution was successful.

What is the simplest and correct way to accomplish that?

I read somewhere that `AJAX` will help but right now, I have very little knowledge of `AJAX` so maybe a simple solution to this is better.

I'd appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: Ajax is 'simple' start learning it...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bean variable:

```
@ManagedBean(name="myBean")
public class MyBean {
  private boolean isSuccessful = false;

  public boolean isSuccessful() { return isSuccessful; }

  public String register(){
     isSuccessful = ...
  }
}
```

and in your xhtml

```xml
     ....
  <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{myBean.register()}" />
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="outtext" />
  </h:commandButton>
  <h:panelGroup id="outtext">
    <h:outputText value="any Text" rendered="#{myBean.successful} />
  </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Thanks, my thinking was about primefaces